# how to remove the index.php from the url in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I wish to remove the index.php in the url of a laravel 4.2 site. But i don't know how to do that. Without index.php/ the pages are not loading. My routes.php contains

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');

Route::get('login','HomeController@home');

Route::get('forgotpassword', 'LoginController@ForgotPassword');

Route::post('loginprocess', 'LoginController@loginprocess');

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
Route::get('locations','LocationController@locations');
Route::get('createlocation','LocationController@createlocation');
Route::post('createlocation','LocationController@savelocation');
Route::get('editlocation/{data}','LocationController@editlocation');
Route::post('editlocation/{data}','LocationController@updatelocation');
Route::get('deletlocation/{data}','VendorController@deletevendor');

Route::post('statusactiveLocation/{data}','LocationController@statusactiveLocation');
Route::post('statusinactiveLocation/{data}','LocationController@statusinactiveLocation');

Route::get('vendors','VendorController@vendors');
Route::get('createvendor','VendorController@createvendor');
Route::post('createvendor','VendorController@savevendor');
Route::get('editvendor/{data}','VendorController@editvendor');
Route::post('editvendor/{data}','VendorController@updatevendor');
Route::get('deletevendor/{data}','VendorController@deletevendor');

Route::post('statusactiveVendor/{data}','VendorController@statusactiveVendor');
Route::post('statusinactiveVendor/{data}','VendorController@statusinactiveVendor');

Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@Logout');
});
```

Comment: What HTTP server are you using Apache, nginx, etc? You need to configure the web server to allow for url rewriting. Have you done that?

Comment: Could you show your routes?

Comment: This is not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
To remove the “index.php” suffix from the end of your Laravel applications url, use one of the two methods below.

This also works for removing the public from your url
```

**Method1**.

```
At the minimum use the following code and put it in your “public” folder inside an htaccess file. Make the public folder the root of your application.

Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Method2**.

```
 If you do not have access to change you application’s root folder to public, put the following code in your application’s root directory(which presumably is the one where public is contained in) inside of a .htaccess file.

Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```